# Update main page from views inside ngview in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have a AngularJS SPA application. The main page includes an ng-view directive and a textbox with ng-model bind.
I have some views that display inside ng-view. I have a variable is shared between these views so I used a service for that.
My Issue is when I click a button inside the views this variable changed. I want to display the changed value inside the textbox in main page as soon as it changed.
My Code is As below:

```
 <div data-ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        {{countResult}}
    </div>
    <ng-view class="content"></ng-view>
</div>
```

I update counterResult inside view which is loaded in ngview. I want the counterResult get updated.

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 2):

so you want to access a value from outside of the ng-view scope, in the inside of the ng-view scope. check this code, which I've tested on jsbin and it works fine:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div data-ng-app="demoApp" ng-init="data.countResult='test'">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        Outside ng-view: {{data.countResult}} <br>
    </div>
    <ng-view class="content"></ng-view>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and your app.js file which you have to add in index.html file:

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template: '<div>Inside ng-view: {{data.countResult}}<br><input ng-model="data.countResult"/></div>',
            controller: 'viewMainController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });                    
    }])
    .controller('testController', ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){

    }])
    .controller('viewMainController', function($scope){

    });
```

Here in your testController scope you're defining the countResult value which will not be found in another scope that isn't prototypically inherited from testController. Here you ng-view isn't child of testController so it won't get the value of countResult. So here you can put you countResult value in the $rootScope. As all $scope are children of $rootScope it will get the value in side the ng-view. Hope the explanation make sense.

Comment: It is a bit different. I want to change the main page countResult inside viewMainController.

Comment: I've changed the code according to your requirement. Check now. As you need to change the out side countResult data when it changes inside the ng-view, the solution is you use ng-init to initiate the countResult with data.countResult which will be in rootscope. then from anywhere inside ng-view you change it, it will reflect at outside as  you are using data(dot)countResult. check in js bin: http://jsbin.com/qoqudepiyu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Or you can use Factory to share the same data between controllers.

Comment: I think is correct. but I couldn't understand. All codes in your controllers are commented.

Comment: In controller I didn't need to do anything to show the demo. But if you do change the data.countResult in controller it would reflect on outside the ng-view, as I've initialize it with ng-init at root scope and used data.countResult data(dot)countResult so inside any child scope it will get that data.countResult. and if you change that in child scope it will reflect on parent scope